# Digitally Signing Email

Tags: .net, email, digital-signature, system.net.mail

I have an application which is sending out customer statements. I have a request to digitally sign the email (with pdf attachment) from a few customer. I am using System.Net.Mail currently to send email. I can't seem to find a clear answer, can this be accomplished in .NET or should I look into a 3rd party component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Mail.dll email component](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/):

```
IMail email = Mail.Text("This is message body")
  .Subject("Test")
  .From(new MailBox("mail@in_the_certificate.com", "Alice"))
  .To(new MailBox("bob@mail.com", "Bob"))
  .AddAttachment(@"c:\invoice.pdf")
  .SignWith(new X509Certificate2("TestCertificate.pfx", ""))
  .Create();

using (Smtp smtp = new Smtp())
{
    smtp.Connect("smtp.server.com");
    smtp.Ehlo();
    smtp.Login("user", "password");
    smtp.SendMessage(email);
    smtp.Close();
}
```

You can also use Mail.dll's template engine to create the message body.

Disclaimer: Please note that it is a commercial product (reasonly priced though) that I helped to create.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/74e4711e-1f66-43a7-9e3b-bc9cfbcd1b73/) some code for signing the message. It makes sense to use more powerful third-party components, though. Our SecureBlackbox product includes [MIMEBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-mime.php) package which offers full scope of MIME and S/MIME operations.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout Peter Everett's [project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/CPI_NET_SecureMail.aspx?display=Print) on CodeProject.  I've used it before for sending encryped emails and it works great.